# Passing TextBox value between two UserForms

Tags: vba, excel

I have two user forms in Excel VBA. I enter a value in the `TextBox` at the first `UserForm`. How do I pass the value to the second `UserForm` to display same value in a `TextBox` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your forms are named:

- `Userform1` for this first form
- `Userform2` for the second form

And assuming that you have two textboxes one in each form as follow:

- `TextBox1` for the first textbox located in your first form
- `TextBox2` for the second textbox located in the second form

You assign the value of the first `TextBox1` to `TextBox2` using `Userform2.TextBox2.Text=Userform1.TextBox1.Text`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a public variable:

i.e `X`. In user form 1 `x=textbox1.value` and in user form2 `textbox2.value=X`.